# How to click on a hiperlink within a table?

Tags: selenium, click, href, hidden

I'm trying to download a CSV file by clicking on a link that's located on a hidden table, but I can't make it click on it. The href will change, so I can't use it. I tried to locate it by xPath, partial link text, link text, class name... I also tried to first access the "table" where the button is and then click on the link, but it didn't work as well. Oh, I tried to execute the script too
The table is hidden (class = escondido; means hidden), even though I can see the link.

I'm learning to code, so I'm having a lot of trouble.

PS: I'm using selenium

Comment: can you share the HTML source for that?

Comment: Please share a link to that web page or at least the HTML code of it.